# Monitorar se arquivos foram inseridos em uma pasta especifica

Tags: windows, arquivo, download, diretório

Bom dia amigos,

Gostaria de uma opinião ou sujestao de voces na segunte situação:

Em um dos clientes da empresa que trabalho a responsavel pelo setor financeiro diariamente faz um download de um arquivo do site do banco. Apos o download
este arquivo deve ficar em uma pasta especifica. Nós da TI precisamos monitorar se o arquivo esta sendo baixado e inserido na pasta diariamente. Hoje precisamos
conectar remotamente e olha se o arquvio esta na pasta. Gostaria de automatizar este processo, de alguma forma sermos avisados que o arquivo foi inserido na pasta
pois caso não recebamos este aviso iremos considerar que o arquivo não foi baixado, emfim.. seria isso.

Alguma sugestão ? Eu li sobre um software chamado Directory Monitor, sera que resolveria esta demanda?...

obs. o SO do cliente é windows.

Comment: a sua pergunta está fora de escopo

Comment: http://www.macoratti.net/vbn5_fsw.htm

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma tarefa no "**Agendador de Tarefas**" no windows do cliente que será executada de tempo em tempo com um script .vbs que verifica se um determinado arquivo existe e se existir ele envia um e-mail.

Crie um arquivo chamado **verifica.vbs** e coloque o conteúdo abaixo:

```
Option Explicit
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
nomeArquivo = "c:\teste.txt" 'nome do arquivo do cliente

' verifica se o arquivo existe
If (objFSO.FileExists(nomeArquivo)) Then       
   enviaEmail  'se existir envia email  
Else 
   WScript.Quit() 
End If

Sub EnviaEmail()
   Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   objEmail.From = "jesiel@contoso.msft" ' <- informe o e-mail de saída 
   objEmail.To = "destino@contoso.msft"  ' <- informe para qual e-mail deve enviar
   objEmail.Subject = "Arquivo recebido" ' <- informe o assunto do e-mail
   objEmail.TextBody =  "ARQUIVO RECEBIDO" ' <- informe o texto 
   objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
   objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "10.0.0.1" '<-informe seu servidor smtp
   objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 '<- informe a porta smtp de envio de email
   objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
   objEmail.Send   
End sub
```

Passei a lógica agora basta aplicar da melhor forma para lhe atender.